# How to effectively manage a big number of Java runnable tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, executor

I have a database table which has 100K+ identifiers. The task is to read each of these IDs and start time consuming enrichment process the result of which, once completed, needs to be persisted into database.

Current Java based solution is based on following flow:

- Load all identifiers from the database into memory;
- Create ThreadPool with 10 threads;
- Start parallel processing / tasks which perform enrichment and persist data into database ( 50 IDs per task, in parallel). All tasks are being added into queue.

Java ThreadPool and Executor framework are used to accommodate this functionality.

Future expectation is that number of identifiers will grow dramatically, so to avoid potential memory pressure - I am thinking to start reading IDs in batches and create associated task when one of the existing tasks has been completed ( i.e. on demand ).

For instance, at the beginning, in the main thread, get 500 IDs from the database, create 10 tasks ( 50 IDs per task ), pass them to worker threads to handle them and once first task is completed - pull additional IDs from the database and create an additional task. Then repeat the process until all IDs are processed.

The question I have is how to notify the main thread that particular task / tasks have been completed to allow main thread to pull additional IDs from the database and create an additional task?
Is this the best way to approach this problem or another architecture will be better in that case?

Comment: Exactly what part of the work do you expect to be a problem wih memory? The creation of the instances of your Runnable/Callable task objects?

Comment: Thank you, will get it changed.

Answer (score 2):

When you submit a Runnable/Callable object to an executor service, you get back a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object. You can track those `Future` objects, and ask their status. Each will report if it was cancelled or completed.

When all completed, submit another batch of Runnable/Callable tasks to the executor service.

You would run this `Future`-checker batch-submitter as yet another task on a background thread, using a `ScheduledExecutorService` to execute repeatedly. The main thread is not involved directly.

Beyond that, I suggest you check your assumptions. Apparently you are concerned about instantiating millions of Runnable/Callable objects for fear of blowing out memory. But I doubt each Runnable/Callable object, and resulting `Future` object, takes much memory. I suggest you run a simulation to see, and check memory usage with a monitor or profiling tool.

Here is some example code. First my `Callable`.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public record Enrichment(Integer id) implements Callable
{
    @Override
    public Boolean call ( ) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println( this.toString() );
        return Boolean.TRUE; // Report success.
    }
}
```

And some code to book 10 million instances of that runnable, and accumulate each of the `Future` objects produced when submitting to an executor service.

```java
Instant start = Instant.now();
System.out.println( "INFO - Start running demo at " + start );

int limit = 10_000_000;
List < Future > futures = new ArrayList <>( limit );
ExecutorService executorService = null;
try
{
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 3 );
    for ( int i = 1 ; i <= limit ; i++ )
    {
        Callable < Boolean > callable = new Enrichment( i );
        Future < Boolean > future = executorService.submit( callable );
        futures.add( future );
    }
    System.out.println( "INFO - Submitted %d tasks.".formatted( limit ) );
}
finally
{
    if ( Objects.nonNull( executorService ) ) { executorService.shutdown(); }
}

// Sleep our main thread long enough for background work to finish.
try
{
    System.out.println( "INFO - Sleeping main thread." );
    Thread.sleep( TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis( 1 ) );
}
catch ( InterruptedException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Instant done = Instant.now();
System.out.println( "INFO - Done running demo at " + done );
```

Note that I need not really instantiate new objects in this particular case of `Enrichment` class. We could simply re-use a single instance across all 10 million executions of `run`. But I wanted a worse-case example — in case your scenario did demand fresh objects, I wanted to see the approximate impact on memory.

In my trials using Java 15 from AdoptOpenJDK on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 on 64-bit Intel Mac mini, the work took less than a minute, and used 4.5 gigs for a volume of 10 million tasks.

---

By the way, in the future, [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) may simplify your work. You will be able to simply schedule millions of « virtual threads » (fibers) to run on a limited number of platform/kernel threads. Project Loom Early-Access [Builds are available now](https://jdk.java.net/loom/). See late 2020 presentations by Ron Pressler on YouTube.

Comment: Thank you, Basil, for your comment.The main concern is that otherwise all IDs (millions or records) will need to be loaded into memory in one go and huge number of runnable tasks need to be queued at the same time.
I was thinking instead of waiting for the whole batch (for instance 10 tasks) completion, check each future separately so that when the first one is completed immediately create a new task with to process new set of IDs. If future fails (remote service timeout) then make an attempt to re-run it.Does it overcomplicate an implementation logic (or it's simply not the best practices)?

Comment: @Dmytro I do not see a problem with queueing millions of Runnable/Callable tasks with an executor service, not in terms of jamming the queue. Queuing tasks is the central job of an executor service. I don't know of any particular limit in the range of millions. But I suppose you could peruse the source code. And try an experiment, as I suggested in the Answer.

Comment: @Dmytro  Regarding how to handle failed tasks, I do not know the best practices on that.

Answer (score 0):

method from @Basil Bourque is very good,i have another method hope can help you.

- task process need more time so load all IDS from database to memory is no needed.
- your must have a batch query method which can get 500 IDs from database every time.
- use method call to implement notify main thread.

I write a very simple code about this:

```java
public class BatchTaskExecutor {

    // contains method about query from database
    private final TaskRepository taskRepository;

    private final List<List<Task>> needProcessedTasks = new LinkedList<>();

    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public BatchTaskExecutor(TaskRepository taskRepository) {
        this.taskRepository = taskRepository;
    }

    public void process() {
        executorService.submit(() -> {
            loadTasks();
            Mono<Boolean> processResult = taskProcess();
            processResult.block();
        });
    }

    // load tasks from database and partition to ten list for parallel process 
    private void loadTasks() {
        List<Task> tasks = taskRepository.batchQuery();

        List<List<Task>> partitionTasks = Lists.partition(tasks, 50);
        needProcessedTasks.clear();
        needProcessedTasks.addAll(partitionTasks);
    }

    // use reactor to parallel process
    private Mono<Boolean> taskProcess() {
        return Flux.range(0, 10)
            .parallel(10)
            .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .flatMap((Function<Integer, Publisher<List<Task>>>) integer -> Mono.just(needProcessedTasks.get(integer)))
            .flatMap((Function<List<Task>, Publisher<Boolean>>) tasks -> Mono.just(batchProcessTask(tasks))).reduce(new BiFunction<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(Boolean aBoolean, Boolean aBoolean2) {
                return aBoolean && aBoolean2;
            }
        }).doOnSuccess(aBoolean -> {
            if (aBoolean) {
                batchSave();
                process();
            } else {
                // todo realize retry method
            }
        });
    }

    // simulate long time need task
    private boolean batchProcessTask(List<Task> tasks) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
        }
        for (Task task : tasks) {
            task.setStatus(true);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void batchSave() {
        System.out.println("begin to save task");
        taskRepository.batchSave(needProcessedTasks.stream()
            .flatMap(new Function<List<Task>, Stream<Task>>() {
                @Override
                public Stream<Task> apply(List<Task> tasks) {
                    return tasks.stream();
                }
            }).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        needProcessedTasks.clear();
    }
}
```